# How to change IntelliJ IDEA logging level?

Tags: logging, intellij-idea

I'm usging IJ 2017.1.3 and currently I'm trying to troubleshoot a local issue related with gradle import in IDEA. I found that idea provides the logs using `Help -> Show log in finder/explorer`, but there's only INFO level.

I also found the option under `Help -> Debug log settings...` where i'm supposed to provide the categories. I tried the following configuration but still only INFO level in `idea.log` file

```
ij.compiler
org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle
```

I may misunderstood what's meant by category here. Any ideas?

Comment: `bin/log.xml` you can enable debug for all categories.

Comment: @CrazyCoder: Great!  Now what's a "category"?

Comment: @nobar `<root><priority value="INFO"/>...` change to  `DEBUG`.

Comment: How can we locate the bin/log.xml file?

Answer (score 14):

So, there are some resources from Jetbrains people out of there, but the page that explained properly this part was [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203855890-com-intellij-openapi-diagnostic-Logger-debug-statements-are-not-visible-in-the-console).

You must put the fully qualified name of the class you need to debug. It may be that this does not correspond to the registered name of the logger for that class. For instance, if you use `com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger`, then it prepends a `#` before the fully qualified name, e.g. for class `com.example.MyClass` you would have `#com.example.MyClass`.

I tested the thingy and it works. Beware that if you are using IntelliJ sandbox for testing your own plugin, then you must set the debug configuration in the running sandbox and not in the IDE you use for dev purposes.

Comment: `Beware that if you are using IntelliJ sandbox for testing your own plugin, then you must set the debug configuration in the running sandbox and not in the IDE you use for dev purposes.` Argh, This was exactly my problem! I'm sorry but IntelliJ's plug in system is terribly documented. Thank you for posting this! (Although we shouldn't have to rely on random SO answers to figure this out >_>)